# How to determine the subject and object of an object property assertion?

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, owl-api

In OWLAPI, when you get the signature of an `OWLAxiom` of type `AxiomType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_ASSERTION`, how to know which of its entities is the subject and which is the object?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do it from the signature.  The signature is just a set, and doesn't have the information that you want.  Instead, treat it as an [OWLPropertyAssertionAxiom](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLPropertyAssertionAxiom.html) and use the [getSubject()](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLPropertyAssertionAxiom.html#getSubject%28%29) and [getObject()](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLPropertyAssertionAxiom.html#getObject%28%29) methods.